# Why i can't put data into Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am doing a simple Registration page and I have a problem. I can't put users' data in the firestore database. I did it with Realtime Database but with firestore there is a problem and I don't know what it is. Here is the code :

```
CollectionReference UsersRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users");

    if (UsersRef != null) {

        HashMap<String, Object> userDataMap = new HashMap<>();
        userDataMap.put("phone",phoneNumber);
        userDataMap.put("password",password);
        userDataMap.put("name",name);

        UsersRef.document(phoneNumber).update(userDataMap).addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {

            // First TOAST
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Congratulations, your account has been created.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();

            startLoginActivity();

        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            loadingBar.dismiss();

            //SECOND TOAST
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Network error, please try again later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Votre reference USERS n'a pas été créée",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I'm getting the user's inputs with variables name, phone number, and password.
If everything is fine, the first toast appears.
if the operation didn't work, the second toast appears.

Comment: Have you checked your firestore rules? They could be blocking the write. You might want to try printing the stacktrace of the error provider by the failureListener for more details about what error occurred

Comment: Also, you are using update() here. The docs mention that update will only work if a document already exists. Perhaps you meant to use set() which will create if it doesn't exist or update the document if it does exist?

Comment: Thanks ! the problem was coming from the rules and i changed update() with set() after that

Comment: What the message in the second toast? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of giving this post an answer:

As Tom Bailey has correctly commented, the code above is using the update() operation. [On this official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) you can find very useful information about the set() and update() operations.

TL:DR

Set(): creates or overwrites a single document. If the document does not exist, it will be created. If the document does exist, its contents will be overwritten with the newly provided data.

Update(): updates some fields of a document without overwriting the entire document.